# Coulomb's law and electric field intensity

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, coulombs-law

[image]

here is question and solution

I can't understand why R_x= 4a_z 
please explain it detail! ;-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The electric field from any single line charge always points directly away from the line charge, is proportional to the linear charge density, and falls off like $\frac{1}{r}$

In your problem, at any point of interest, you will have an electric field vector that has a component on the y-z plane from the line charge on the x axis, and a component on the x-z plane from the line charge on the y axis.

The total magnitude will be $E=\sqrt{E_{yz}^2 + E_{xz}^2}$

Comment: I understand whole your comment, but I don't catch why R_x= 4a_z still...